# How to securely get dynamic IP address of home network

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I am running a raspberry pi and some services on my home network. My ISP provides a dynamic IP address as a public IP to me. I have port mapping and all set up so that if I get my public IP address (which is dynamic), I can access things. But problem is that how do I get the updated public IP address if I am away from my home?

Is there a way to securely convey the new dynamic IP address to me every time it changes?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a way to get a new dynamic public IP address every time it changes?

> No-IP Free Dynamic DNS is our entry level service. Use
>   yourname.no-ip.info instead of a hard to remember IP address or URL to
>   access your computer remotely. Additionally, use our free dynamic DNS
>   update client to keep track of your dynamic IP address. You will
>   always be able to access your computer even if your IP address is
>   dynamically assigned.

Source [Free Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com/free)